# Google Chrome full-page screenshot with iframes

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to capture a full page screenshot, but I'm having problems because my page includes iframes. The Google Chrome full-page screenshot feature is only capturing what is displayed on the screen. I've also tried a few extensions. Fireshot comes close, but it repeats the menu at the top of each screen section.

Is there any way in the Google Chrome developer tools to use the full page capture for a specific iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I was pleasantly surprised that this extension took a screenshot of my entire iframe. (I do not know or work with the developer.)

https://github.com/mrcoles/full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension